# Solrnet index data post object list

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I use solrnet to index data like below :

```
        var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility("http://mysolr:8983/solr/testcollection");
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);
        var solr = container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<Dictionary<string, object>>>();
        solr.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> {
            {"id", "http://google.com/link1"},
            {"title", "test.pdf"},
            {"content", "abcdefghijk"},
            {"author", "Ziv Hsu"},
            {"editor", "Ziv Hsu"},
        });
        solr.Commit();
```

It's work;

but if I have a object list need to index 
is not work it'll get 400 code like below:

```
public class LSchemaField
{
    public List<SchemaField> SchemaFieldList = new List<SchemaField>();
}
public class SchemaField
{
    public virtual string id { get; set; }
    .....
}

        LSchemaField SchemaFieldList = new LSchemaField();

        SchemaField SchemaFields = new SchemaField();
        SchemaFields.id = ....;         
        SchemaFieldList.SchemaFieldList.Add(SchemaFields);

        SchemaField SchemaFields2 = new SchemaField();
        SchemaFields2.id =....;
        SchemaFieldList.SchemaFieldList.Add(SchemaFields2);

        var solrFacility = new  SolrNetFacility("http://mysolr:8983/solr/testcollection");
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);
        var solr = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<LSchemaField>>();enter code here
        solr.Add(SchemaFieldList );
        solr.Commit();
```

Can it add a object list?

Answer (score 0):

In SchemaField class you need to set SchemaField attribute for each property which you want to add in solr.this will map properties to solr fileds.
https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md

Comment: Hi Prakash Bhatt

but my solr is has use schema.xml
it same need to mapping Schemafield?